# Controlling mosfet with a battery-powered attiny85

Tags: transistors, batteries, mosfet, switches, attiny85

I have to control a MOSFET in switch mode. However, the whole circuit including AtTiny is powered by a LiPo battery. AFAIK AtTiny's output pin voltage is somewhere between 0.8*Vdd and Vdd and I'm worried that the voltage between gate and source is unpredictable. At least it can be 0.2*Vdd, which probably can be not enough to open MOSFET fully. Isn't it better to use a bipolar transistor before MOSFET?

So, my idea is that if we can't control voltage on the gate, we can control current, and open bipolar one with it, which gives the battery's voltage level on the gate.

Or maybe I'm wrong and here isn't a problem at all?

The load is a gprs+gps chip and my AtTiny is a kind of watchdog and peripheral controller for it. The maximum MOSFET current is about 2.2A. It's possible to use n-channel FET on gnd side, but it would be much much harder to trace because it has about 8 gnd's pins.

I'm going to use IRLML5203, but want my scheme to be capable to work with other models, with different Rds.

Thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRIuTJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your schematics will just not work and why do they show the wrong MOSFET part number.

Comment: I've just used default elements from the circuit editor

Comment: Typically you can directly drive a small to medium *low side* NFET.  It's if you insist on having a high side switch for a supply rail above the processor's that you need an intermediate switching element.  But your circuit diagrams are too incomplete.  Describe your actual need - what is the supply voltage and current you need to switch?  Can you switch the low side, or must it be the high?

Comment: I've tried to add it into the question

Comment: Again, please fix your circuit diagrams (ie, make them be actual circuits, not open circuit fragments), explain the actual nature of the load, and be clear if you can use low side switching.  If your ATmega is powered by the same rail as the FET's load, this *might* work, but you need to check if the FET will be sufficiently on at lower supply voltages when the battery is nearing end of cycle.

Comment: Yes, everything is powered by the same battery. And my question is about low voltages. Would it better to use n-channel? Why? I'm a newbie in electronics

Comment: "The load is a gprs+gps chip" in that case you'll need to document all connections between the ATmega or other always powered components, and the power switched ones.  Generally speaking it is neither permitted nor workable to have I/O voltages run to a switched off device (you not only violate the absolute maximum specifications, you also get an undesired power drain on the I/O).  With proper design of that issue however, a logic level PFET would indeed be a common solution for the sort of thing you are trying to do.

Comment: IMHO the IRLM5203 would be a bit marginally on towards the end of the battery discharge given the high pulse transmit currents of GSM.  You want something with better low voltage performance, eg compare the drain current curves of the DMP2035U-7 at low gate voltages to that of your part.  There are likely even more suitable choices, that's just a number stuck in *my* memory from a long past use.

Comment: The only connection between GPRS chip and attiny is i2c bus. I can switch these pins off (high-z state). Would it be enough? Thanks for your advice. Gprs subsystem is quite isolated and powered with this FET. All the other peripherals are controlled by attiny